# rewriting simple conditional loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm doing some refactoring and was wondering if from this original code:

```
applyPlant(plant: ExportPlant): void {
  if (plant.transfer) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.plants.length; ++i) {
          if (this.plants[i] === plant) {
              return;
          }
      }
      this.plants.push(plant);
  } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.plants.length; ++i) {
          if (this.plants[i] === plant) {
              this.plants.splice(i, 1);
              return;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

rewriting it as:

```
applyPlant(plant: ExportPlant): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.plants.length; ++i) {
        if (this.plants[i] === plant) {
            if (!plant.transfer) {
                this.plants.splice(i, 1);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    if (plant.transfer) {
        this.plants.push(plant);
    }
}
```

would be a good idea. Do they behave the same? Is the second version more readable? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Why don't you simply extract two methods? No need to read 3 times the loop to understand what's the condition to `.push(plant)` or not...

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/42632).

Comment: No need for the loop find the item using indexOf `this.plants.indexOf(plant)` then add or remove depending on `plant.transfer ? (index===-1 && (this.plants.push(plant)) : (index > -1 && (this.plants.splice(index,1)));` but with a few if's and else's to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are equivalent, but when posting here, normally you should already know that.

Both versions have benefits and drawbacks,
neither is better than the other in an absolute sense.
The first has the benefit of checking the condition `plant.transfer` only once,
the second has the benefit of being more compact.

The purpose of the method can be summarized as,
"when `plant.transfer` is `true`, add `plant` if it's not already in `this.plants`, otherwise remove it if it's there".
An alternative implementation of this logic, not necessarily better,
is to encapsulate the action to take when a matching item and after the iteration is completed in functions:

```
const nop = () => {};
var onFound = nop, onMissing = nop;

if (plant.transfer) {
    onMissing = () => this.plants.push(plant);
} else {
    onFound = (index) => this.plants.splice(index, 1);
}

for (let i = 0; i < this.plants.length; ++i) {
    if (this.plants[i] === plant) {
        onFound(i);
        return;
    }
}
onMissing(this.plants);
```